# AngularJS - sortable tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I wanted to create sortable tabs using *uiSortable* directive (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) and tabs from AngularUI bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Important thing for me is an ability to sort elements in model, by using `ng-model`. So, I added `ui-sortable` and `ng-model="someArray"` on  element. It doesn't work that way, because tabset is being replaced with structure like that:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>tab 1 header</li>
    <li>tab 2 header</li>
    <li>tab 3 header</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content"> tabs content </div>
</div>
```

and in effect, *sortable* is applied to outer div so I can grab `ul` and `.tab-content` when in fact I wanted to sort those `li` elements.

My first try on solving that problem was creating *uiSortableTabs* directive with *compile* function that adds `ui-sortable` attribute to `ul` (using just `attr()`). Good thing is that now tabs are sortable. Bad thing is that now sortable is not aware of model. I tried invoking `.attr('ng-model',attrs.ngModel)` on that `ul` together with adding that `ui-sortable`. Now sortable see the model, but it's `undefined`.

Does anyone know **how to make sortable tabs with updatable model** or **how to correctly add directive to an element, together with ngModel using *compile* function in other directive**?

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a similar one, my solution is to use jQuery ui sortable directly and change the data model by hooking the start and stop event.